# Why is the order of execution wrong (assignment and cout)?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner at programming in C++ so I'll try to describe my problem as accurate as I can.
I have an 2D array (should represent a nxn Matrix) which was declared in an *.hpp file as

```
double **A;
double **B;
double **C;
```

Values were assigned to B and C in the corresponding *.cpp file. After that A was assigned to B via
    A = B;

I wanted to change only the first row of A to the first row of C, and print out the result, so I did this:

```
cout << "row 0 of B" << vector<double>(B[0],B[0]+n) << endl;
cout << "row 0 of C" << vector<double>(C[0],C[0]+n) << endl;
cout << "row 0 of A before change" << vector<double>(A[0],A[0]+n) << endl;
A[0] = C[0];
cout << "row 0 of A after change" << vector<double>(A[0],A[0]+n) << endl;
```

But somehow the first cout gives me the same result as the 2nd cout, although the values should be different. If I delete the "A[0] = C[0];", I get the correct result. Somehow the assignment was done first, and then came the cout.
Can somebody explain?

Comment: Off topic: `double **A;` and it's pals look like they were defined in the hpp file. This is something you want to avoid because if multiple CPP files include the same hpp file they will all have their own variable `A` and when presented with multiples of the same identifier the linker will exit with an error message.

Comment: This shouldn't happen, statements are executed in order. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you saying that the `before change` line actually printed the value that it should print after the change?

Comment: Are you sure you filled in the arrays correctly? Double-indirect arrays are often confusing for beginners.